# Difference between %QUOTE and %BQUOTE

Tags: sas

In several occasions I wonder what is the clear difference between `QUOTE` and `BQUOTE`  and therefore `NRQUOTE` and `NRBQUOTE`.

And How `SUPERQ` is different from them?

Comment: [Don’t %QUOTE() Me on This: A Practical Guide to Macro Quoting Functions](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/152-2007.pdf) SGF 2007, Brian Patterson, The College Board, New York, NY Mylene Remigio, The College Board, New York, NY , or any of the other results from https://lexjansen.com/search/searchresults.php?q=bquote

Comment: Hi, this is a very broad question. I suggest you read some of the papers Richard linked to.  Then after that if you have a more specific question about the differences in how the different quoting functions should be used, make up a little example that illustrates your question.  I use only four of the macro quoting functions: %STR %NRSTR %BQUOTE and %SUPERQ.  I think %NRBQUOTE is useless.  %QUOTE and %NRQUOTE are older functions, replaced by %BQUOTE and %NRBQUOTE.